# How to get vector selector drawable in Java code

Tags: android, vector-graphics

I used vector selector drawable in xml which works well, but crash in Java code when sdk < 21.

Here is my xml usage:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/common_selector_ic_back"/>
```

**common_selecor_ic_back.xml**

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/common_ic_back" />
</selector>
```

**common_ic_back.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M20,11H7.83l5.59,-5.59L12,4l-8,8 8,8 1.41,-1.41L7.83,13H20v-2z"/>
```

But I want to change the drawableLeft in code, I tried three solution, both failed.

**1**

```
Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_selector_ic_back);
```

**crashed with**

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/common_selector_ic_back.xml from drawable resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f080065

**2**

```
icon2 = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.common_selector_ic_back);
```

**failed with same reason**

**3**

```
VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), R.drawable.common_selector_ic_back, context.getTheme());
```

**failed with log**

> Binary XML file line #2 tag requires viewportWidth > 0

Any one meet the problem? Can you tell me how to get vector selector drawable in hardware code.

**Solution:**

The activity must be `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Can you paste an image of your res hierarchy specifically the drawable folder.

Comment: Please see the image in question body.

Comment: this might be helpful https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/457

Comment: You cannot directly use Vector with <selector> .. To overcome this problem, use the below steps in my solution.

Comment: `final Drawable d = getDrawable(context, R.drawable.abc_vector_test);` in AppCompatDrawableManager#checkVectorDrawableSetup return true, The VectorDrawableCompat can create `vector` resource, but it can't create `selector` resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Activity to extends AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Try these steps below:

First, Add this line in your `common_ic_back.xml`

```
<vector
    ...
    android:tintMode="multiply"
    ...>

    ......
    ......

</vector>
```

Then, Don't forget to add `build.gradle(Module:app)` or the approach will not work on old Android versions.

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ....
}
```

Lastly, add this in you `activity` class, before `onCreate()` where you are using this vector:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

Try it. Hope it helps. Please comment if any doubts.

Comment: I add step1 tintMode to vector, but also crash when calling getDrawable(), step2 and step3 I had added to build.gradle

Comment: What does the crash log say

Comment: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/common_selector_ic_back.xml from drawable resource ID
0x7f080065  
I had know the problem to change my activity to extends AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @JamlingLi Is your problem now resolved after changing?